# oracle 11g database connection for java 1.7 version

Tags: java

can we connect to oracle 11g from java 1.7 version. if yes, how? and what classpath do we need to set to avoid class not found error for the class OracleDriver?

Comment: You need the [JDBC-driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver).

Comment: http://bit.ly/1j2syW1

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no difference from previous versions. This is Oracle's documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

What you need is the driver (a jar file downloadable from Oracle) to be in your classpath and loading it using reflection before you use it (there's an example in the link).

Answer (score 0):

you can dowload the drivers from [oracle 11g driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) and add it to classpath.

Answer (score 0):

For any java program, any of your library files should be included in the path of CLASSPATH. For example, you have saved your library MyLibrary.jar in /home/program/lib , then you should execute export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/program/lib

For JDBC, you can download JDBC library from Oracle website. You put the JAR file into the CLASSPATH path you are using, then you can call it.

For flexible design, you should not hardcode the classname of JDBC driver. Instead, you can define it in an external text file so that you can change the value of JDBC driver classname without changing codes.